# PHP Function Call handler

Tags: php, function

Is there anything in php for function handler? Like if I call any function in PHP. Function handler automatically call.

```
function add($i ,$j){
    $k = $i+$j;
    return $k;
}
```

So if someone call above function, function handler automatically execute.
Like we have other function session save_handler, or error_handler in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You should use delegation instead

```
function otherFunction ($i, $k) {
  foobar();
  return add($i, $j);
}
```

With object orientated design you can also wrap the whole object

```
class A {
  public function add($i, $j) { return $i + $j; }
}
class B extends A {
  public function add($i, $j) { $this->foobar(); return parent::add($i, $j);
  protected foobar() { /* do something useful */ }
}
// or
class C extends A {
  protected $_inner;
  public function __construct (A $inner) { $this->_inner = $inner; 0
  public function add($i, $j) { $this->foobar(); return $this->_inner->add($i, $j); }
  protected foobar() { /* do something useful */ }
}
```

Or anonymous functions like

```
$add = function ($i, $j) {
  foobar();
  return add($i, $j);
};
$add(3, 7);
```

Comment: thanks for your information. Actually we are managing user control and we were managing access control with URL . Now We decided we will manage access control one function level . Now i am writing code inside function user has access for functionality or not. If by mistake i will forgot not entered access control inside function . Then any one call function. Even has access right or not . So i want to check inside function there is code for access checking or not. It is old project and there is number of functions